# how to get a list of dynamo db tables in aws that have a creationDate less than a certain value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I wish to use an aws cli commad that will return a list of dynamodb tables in my aws account where the CreationDateTime is less than a certain value. CreationDateTime is a property that is shown with the describe-table command, but the list-tables command only returns the names of the table. Is there any way I could possibly use a query to filter the names returned by list-tables in accordance with their corresponding CreationDateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - As you noted, `ListTables` only lists the *names* of tables, and there is no request that provides additional information for each table, let alone filter on such information. You'll need to use `ListTables` and then `DescribeTable` on each of those tables. You can run all of those `DescribeTable` requests in parallel to make the whole thing much faster (although there is a practical snag - to do it in parallel, you'll need to have opened a bunch of connections to the server).

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the answer is simply no, the AWS CLI can not do what you want in one query.

You need to resort to shell scripting to chain the necessary `aws` commands, or,
if you are willing to give up the hard requirement that it must be the AWS CLI, an alternative solution (and probably faster than forking off `aws` over and over) is to use a 5 line python script to get the result you want. You can still run this from the command-line, but it won't be the AWS CLI specifically.
Just perform the time arithmetic that suits your specific selection criteria.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
for t in sorted(filter(lambda table: datetime.now(timezone.utc) - table.creation_date_time < timedelta(days=90), ddb.tables.all()), key=lambda table: table.creation_date_time):
    print(f"{t.name}, {str(t.creation_date_time)}")  # tables created in the last 90 days
```